# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_6_input to have shape (87482, 1) but got array with shape (87482, 3)

Tags: python, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

X_train data dimension is 87482, 3.

But I got an error on running with the below code. The error is:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_6_input to have shape (87482, 1) but got array with shape (87482, 3)

My code is:

```py
model = Sequential()
#model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
model.add(LSTM(units=3, input_shape=(X_train_rnn.shape[1],1),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(3, return_sequences=True))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(3))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(X_train_rnn, y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=32)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test_rnn, y_test, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)` should fix the error, but maybe not the entire problem: *how long is each sequence*?

- LSTM full input shape (`batch_shape`) is `(batch_size, timesteps, channels)` - or, equivalently, `(samples, timesteps, features)`
- `batch_size=32` in your `.fit()`,  but if `X_train` dimension is `(87472, 3)`, do you have `87472` samples (sequences) each of length 3 (`timesteps=3`)? If so, you'll need `input_shape=(3, 1)` (univariate data), which is what you get with `(X_train.shape[1], 1)`
- If instead your `timesteps=87462`, you'll need `input_shape=(87462, 3)` - but this is a pretty bad idea, as LSTMs struggle for `timesteps > 0`

I don't know what shapes `X_train_rnn` has, so I wrote the answer in terms of `X_train`. Feel free to clarify.